# Split execution executes one or the other flow, but not both in paralell, spring batch

Tags: spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch

My split execution executes one or the other but not both in parallel, am I doing something wrong?

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}
```

**I want "flow1" and "flow2" to run in parallel**

```
@Bean
public Flow splitFlow( Flow flow1,  Flow flow2) {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("splitFlow")
            .split(taskExecutor())
            .add(flow1, flow2)
            .build();
}
```

**first flow**

```
@Bean
public Flow startFlow(Step step,
                      Step step2) {
    return  new FlowBuilder<Flow>("startFlow")
            .start(step)
            .next(step2)
            .build();
}
```

**job builder**

```
@Bean
public Job job(Flow startFlow,
               Flow splitFlow) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(startFlow)
            .next(splitFlow)
            .end()
            .build();
}


}
```

**log step 3 executed**

```
2022-05-16 21:50:52.865 INFO  SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [step3]
2022-05-16 21:50:52.869 INFO  SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [step4]
2022-05-16 21:50:53.281 INFO  UpdateCandidateRentReader:27 - iteratortrue
2022-05-16 21:50:53.285 INFO  UpdateCandidateRentReader:27 - iteratortrue
2022-05-16 21:50:53.564 DEBUG SQL:128 - update cir_can_rep set flg_norepro=1 where num_credito in (? , ?)
2022-05-16 21:50:54.398 INFO  AbstractStep:272 - Step: [step4] executed in 1s529ms
2022-05-16 21:50:54.533 INFO  AbstractStep:272 - Step: [step3] executed in 1s668ms
```

**log step 4 executed**

```
2022-05-16 22:01:10.603 INFO  SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [step3]
2022-05-16 22:01:10.608 INFO  SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [step4]
2022-05-16 22:01:11.025 INFO  UpdateCandidateRentReader:27 - iteratortrue
2022-05-16 22:01:11.032 INFO  UpdateCandidateRentReader:27 - iteratortrue
2022-05-16 22:01:11.303 INFO  SpringBatchConfig:55 - step 4 flow
2022-05-16 22:01:12.133 INFO  AbstractStep:272 - Step: [step4] executed in 1s525ms
2022-05-16 22:01:12.150 INFO  AbstractStep:272 - Step: [step3] executed in 1s546ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Split Flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#split-flows) section from the reference documentation provides a code sample of how to run two flows in parallel. You need to change your step definition to something like this:

```java
@Bean
public Job job(Flow flow1, Flow flow2) {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(flow1)
                .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .add(flow2)
                .end()
                .build();
}
```